# TensorFlow 2.10.0 build for C++ using Bazel failed with error "Link.exe 1120 failed: error executing command " in Windows 10

Tags: c++, windows, tensorflow, build, gpu

Steps followed:

1. Installed Bazel version 5.1.1 and set the environment variables.
2. Installed msys2 and set the environment variables.
3. Installed visual studio professional 2019 for C++ build .
4. Installed python 3.9.13
5. Installed python dependencies like numpy, wheel, keras
6. Downloaded tensorflow 2.10.0 source from tensorflow github repository
7. Configured TensorFlow with default configuration using ‘./configure’
8. Build TensorFlow using the command
   ‘bazel --host_jvm_args=-Xmx4g --output_base=D:\0 build --jvmopt="-server -Xms2g" --config=opt tensorflow:tensorflow_cc’

While tried to build ‘tensorflow_cc’ with the above command, the compilation is success but the linking failed with error 1120.

The following versions of tools are used for building:
Tensorflow        - 2.10.0
Python - 3.9.13
Visual studio - Professional 2019
Bazel     - 5.1.1
MSYS    - 2
Tried the GPU build with ‘Cuda 11.2 and Cudnn 8.1’ also but the result is same.

Note: Earlier tried to build tensorflow.dll (not tensorflow_cc), for which the compilation and linking was success and tensorflow.dll got generated.
But while linking the tensorflow.dll to visual studio cpp project, I got 'unresolved external symbol errors'. It seems the dll generated by this method has the ‘C’ symbols instead of ‘CPP’ symbols in it.

**Build Error:**

```
D:\TF_Building\cc_tensorflow-2.10.0>bazel --host_jvm_args=-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\security\cacerts" --host_jvm_args=-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit --host_jvm_args=-Xmx4g  build --jvmopt="-server -Xms2g" --config=opt //tensorflow:tensorflow_cc
WARNING: Running Bazel server needs to be killed, because the startup options are different.
Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...
INFO: Options provided by the client:
  Inherited 'common' options: --isatty=1 --terminal_columns=157
INFO: Reading rc options for 'build' from d:\tf_building\cc_tensorflow-2.10.0\.bazelrc:
  Inherited 'common' options: --experimental_repo_remote_exec
INFO: Options provided by the client:
  'build' options: --python_path=C:/Users/1024182/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe
INFO: Reading rc options for 'build' from d:\tf_building\cc_tensorflow-2.10.0\.bazelrc:
  'build' options: --define framework_shared_object=true --define=use_fast_cpp_protos=true --define=allow_oversize_protos=true --spawn_strategy=standalone -c opt --announce_rc --define=grpc_no_ares=true --noincompatible_remove_legacy_whole_archive --enable_platform_specific_config --define=with_xla_support=true --config=short_logs --config=v2 --define=no_aws_support=true --define=no_hdfs_support=true --experimental_cc_shared_library --experimental_link_static_libraries_once=false
INFO: Reading rc options for 'build' from d:\tf_building\cc_tensorflow-2.10.0\.tf_configure.bazelrc:
  'build' options: --action_env PYTHON_BIN_PATH=C:/Users/1024182/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe --action_env PYTHON_LIB_PATH=C:/Users/1024182/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/lib/site-packages --python_path=C:/Users/1024182/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe --copt=/d2ReducedOptimizeHugeFunctions --host_copt=/d2ReducedOptimizeHugeFunctions --define=override_eigen_strong_inline=true
INFO: Reading rc options for 'build' from d:\tf_building\cc_tensorflow-2.10.0\.bazelrc:
  'build' options: --deleted_packages=tensorflow/compiler/mlir/tfrt,tensorflow/compiler/mlir/tfrt/benchmarks,tensorflow/compiler/mlir/tfrt/jit/python_binding,tensorflow/compiler/mlir/tfrt/jit/transforms,tensorflow/compiler/mlir/tfrt/python_tests,tensorflow/compiler/mlir/tfrt/tests,tensorflow/compiler/mlir/tfrt/tests/ir,tensorflow/compiler/mlir/tfrt/tests/analysis,tensorflow/compiler/mlir/tfrt/tests/jit,tensorflow/compiler/mlir/tfrt/tests/lhlo_to_tfrt,tensorflow/compiler/mlir/tfrt/tests/lhlo_to_jitrt,tensorflow/compiler/mlir/tfrt/tests/tf_to_corert,tensorflow/compiler/mlir/tfrt/tests/tf_to_tfrt_data,tensorflow/compiler/mlir/tfrt/tests/saved_model,tensorflow/compiler/mlir/tfrt/transforms/lhlo_gpu_to_tfrt_gpu,tensorflow/core/runtime_fallback,tensorflow/core/runtime_fallback/conversion,tensorflow/core/runtime_fallback/kernel,tensorflow/core/runtime_fallback/opdefs,tensorflow/core/runtime_fallback/runtime,tensorflow/core/runtime_fallback/util,tensorflow/core/tfrt/common,tensorflow/core/tfrt/eager,tensorflow/core/tfrt/eager/backends/cpu,tensorflow/core/tfrt/eager/backends/gpu,tensorflow/core/tfrt/eager/core_runtime,tensorflow/core/tfrt/eager/cpp_tests/core_runtime,tensorflow/core/tfrt/gpu,tensorflow/core/tfrt/run_handler_thread_pool,tensorflow/core/tfrt/runtime,tensorflow/core/tfrt/saved_model,tensorflow/core/tfrt/graph_executor,tensorflow/core/tfrt/saved_model/tests,tensorflow/core/tfrt/tpu,tensorflow/core/tfrt/utils
INFO: Found applicable config definition build:short_logs in file d:\tf_building\cc_tensorflow-2.10.0\.bazelrc: --output_filter=DONT_MATCH_ANYTHING
INFO: Found applicable config definition build:v2 in file d:\tf_building\cc_tensorflow-2.10.0\.bazelrc: --define=tf_api_version=2 --action_env=TF2_BEHAVIOR=1INFO: Found applicable config definition build:opt in file d:\tf_building\cc_tensorflow-2.10.0\.tf_configure.bazelrc: --copt=/arch:AVX --host_copt=/arch:AVX
INFO: Found applicable config definition build:windows in file d:\tf_building\cc_tensorflow-2.10.0\.bazelrc: --copt=/W0 --host_copt=/W0 --copt=/Zc:__cplusplus --host_copt=/Zc:__cplusplus --copt=/D_USE_MATH_DEFINES --host_copt=/D_USE_MATH_DEFINES --features=compiler_param_file --copt=/d2ReducedOptimizeHugeFunctions --host_copt=/d2ReducedOptimizeHugeFunctions --cxxopt=/std:c++17 --host_cxxopt=/std:c++17 --config=monolithic --copt=-DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN --host_copt=-DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN --copt=-DNOGDI --host_copt=-DNOGDI --copt=/experimental:preprocessor --host_copt=/experimental:preprocessor --linkopt=/DEBUG --host_linkopt=/DEBUG --linkopt=/OPT:REF --host_linkopt=/OPT:REF --linkopt=/OPT:ICF --host_linkopt=/OPT:ICF --verbose_failures --features=compiler_param_file --distinct_host_configuration=false
INFO: Found applicable config definition build:monolithic in file d:\tf_building\cc_tensorflow-2.10.0\.bazelrc: --define framework_shared_object=false --experimental_link_static_libraries_once=false
INFO: Analyzed target //tensorflow:tensorflow_cc (269 packages loaded, 20666 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
ERROR: D:/tf_building/cc_tensorflow-2.10.0/tensorflow/BUILD:1156:21: Linking tensorflow/tensorflow_cc.dll failed: (Exit 1120): link.exe failed: error executing command
  cd /d C:/users/1024182/_bazel_1024182/gigze6o2/execroot/org_tensorflow
  SET LIB=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\ATLMFC\lib\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\lib\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\lib\um\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.19041.0\um\x64
    SET PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\\Extensions\Microsoft\IntelliCode\CLI;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX64\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\VCPackages;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\bin\Roslyn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Team Tools\Performance Tools\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Team Tools\Performance Tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Common\VSPerfCollectionTools\vs2019\\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Common\VSPerfCollectionTools\vs2019\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\x64\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\FSharp\Tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\Tools\devinit;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.19041.0\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\\MSBuild\Current\Bin;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\Tools\;;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\Ninja;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\Linux\bin\ConnectionManagerExe
    SET PWD=/proc/self/cwd
    SET PYTHON_BIN_PATH=C:/Users/1024182/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe
    SET PYTHON_LIB_PATH=C:/Users/1024182/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/lib/site-packages
    SET RUNFILES_MANIFEST_ONLY=1
    SET TEMP=C:\Users\1024182\AppData\Local\Temp
    SET TF2_BEHAVIOR=1
    SET TMP=C:\Users\1024182\AppData\Local\Temp
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX64\x64\link.exe @bazel-out/x64_windows-opt/bin/tensorflow/tensorflow_cc.dll-2.params
**# Configuration: 49364d498d2e60c64c08a94404aa46742b697c047bdd88e3c7913989a8abad35
**# Execution platform: @local_execution_config_platform//:platform****
stdout (C:/users/1024182/_bazel_1024182/gigze6o2/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/_tmp/actions/stdout-12130) exceeds maximum size of --experimental_ui_max_stdouterr_bytes=1048576 bytes; skipping
Target //tensorflow:tensorflow_cc failed to build
INFO: Elapsed time: 8002.569s, Critical Path: 968.80s
INFO: 7482 processes: 878 internal, 6604 local.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

**How to solve these linking errors?**